# Vmware Got Hit By Brute Force More Than 60K Attempt

Tags: security, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-server

I have a vmware with 2012 server in it. Recently int he vsphere seens alot of attempt. Smells like a brute force. I understand that Security.AccountUnlockTime exists in the ESXi 6.0 that has a lockout period ( 120 seconds )

But that doesn't seems to be enough to remove the brute force away. How can i remedy this?

Answer (score 6):

Put the VMkernel interface behind a VPN or at the very least a firewall so you can limit what IP addresses can connect to it.

Answer (score 3):

### For Esxi

In ESXi vSphere client, you can restrict access to authorized IP.

In the Esxi server main panel > configuration > Software > Firewall > Incoming connexion

You need to restrict mainly:

- vSphere Client
- SSH (if you enabled it)
- vSphere Web Access

But like me you can restrict all execpt:

- DHCP client (if you use DHCP for ESXI IP)
- DHCPv6 (if you use DHCP v6 for ESXI)
- DNS Client (if you need the DNS client for ESXI)

[image]

### For windows 2012

In you Windows 2012 go to Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings

Add new inbound rules for port 3389 in TCP :

[image]

Then in scope tab to limit IP address add the IPs you want:

[image]